# How to measure how many working days would need by other experienced programmer reproducing sourcecode?

Tags: performance

I have made a framework and for selling / pricing objective I need to estimate the required working days other, on the specific field experienced programmer would use to reproduce it.

I thought I will just trace back in version control system how many days I was working on that special code, but I made several refactoring, I dealt with code though several iteration, experimenting framework took me a long time, and I want to know time it requires to copy and not to create framework.

How would a CTO specify the amount of work to be done in one working day?

How would a CTO specify the amount of working days a feature, programming module requires?

What is the expected number of code lines / added number of method / function point CTO can expect to be done in one working day?

is it any accepted measurement for it or measuring is heuristic?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming.

Comment: in stackoverflow they said it is not programming but performance of employee

Comment: Work estimation is not programming, it's Workplace.  You are right to post here.

Comment: @RossDrew: Work estimation in the abstract is on-topic. Specific guidance about work estimation as it pertains to programming is not. Steve McConnell wrote an entire book on the work estimation for programming. It's that specialized. http://www.amazon.com/Software-Estimation-Demystifying-Developer-Practices/dp/0735605351#

Comment: He wrote a book on Software Estimation.  Software is made up of programming but software isn't programming.  Software estimation is infrastructure, planning, design, programming and testing.  He's asking for working days, not working days spent specifically on programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Good* managers never specify what has to be done in a day or how many days can be used for a feature. They ask their developers what *can* be done in a day or how long they *need* for a feature. Normally, developers err on the optimistic side, so for good measaure, assume they will be 20% late.

The framework is in the state it's currently in because you put in the time you did. That's what it did cost.

Someone selling it would take your cost, add a factor to make some profit and price it that way.

If you think you are not as experienced as someone earning x$ an hour, it may be a lot easier to keep to the facts (the hours you worked) and instead adjust the price of an hour of work.

If you really want to know what it's worth, write up what it provides as requirements and ask other companies what it would cost if you wanted to buy something like it from them. *That's* a good measurement for market value.